# What is causing innerHTML to grab a different amount of HTML each time?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, innerhtml

For work, I'm writing a simple function to get the innerHTML of the body of an iframe that is always on our site (an advertisement). I have access to the first layer of it and I know I can't go deeper than that. The content of this iframe change every page load, have plenty of scripts, divs, and could possibly have a few iframes nested in as well (which I know I can't go into).

`console.log(document.getElementById(fullId).contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);`

The results vary with each time I refresh the page so I'll list a few of my tests here. I also placed a variable for `performance.now()` before and after the grab to see how long each time I refresh it takes to perform the innerHTML. I will also list the type of tag it grabbed last and the first tag it did not read at the stop in a `<tag1>/<tag2>` format. When I list xx/yy tags, I'm counting nodes that are immediately in the `<iframe> <body>` that the innerHTML was able to get the entirety of, including all nested elements.

1) 19,514/19,514 characters, 40/40 tags, 0.5749 milliseconds.

2) 12,366/42,819 characters, 37/41 tags, 8.9200 milliseconds. `<script>/<img>`

3) 44,075/47,891  characters, 15/18 tags, 2.6350 milliseconds. `<iframe>/<style>`

4) 3,236/~300,000+ characters, 17/28 tags, 0.305 milliseconds. This one missed tags in the beginning middle, and end for whatever reason. There were a couple of scripts with a ridiculous amount of characters in them, but it also passed on some div and img tags with barely anything in them.

So as you can see, the results are never really consistent. I should also note that in my tests, there were very few iframes nested within the original iframe and the ones that were, barely contributed to the total characters missed.
 If anyone is able to explain to me why it is acting this way, that would be absolutely fantastic because I've been scratching my head for a while now.

I did my best to explain this for you guys and if you have any questions or things explained further, please let me know.

Comment: im confused. you say the content is different every page load, and your asking why it's different?

Comment: The question is specifically tailored towards the amount and percentage of the overall content it is grabbing. As you can see with each test I ran, it was never really the same. The first time it got 100% of the characters in every tag. Other tests captured significantly less (#4) or more (#3) and each were stalled by different tags that didn't appear any different than the others. Tests 2 & 3 went from the start of the body tag and got everything until it got halted at the points I listed. Test 4 was bizarre in that it didn't get the beginning, or the end, and missed some middle.

Comment: Presumably the iframe contents you're testing are consistent, and the advertiser's content is what changes, and you "know" you aren't checking for that, only the consistent wrapper iframe. The only conclusion I can come up with is that you're not waiting for the body onload event of the iframe. So possibly the content of the iframe body is still loading when you console.log it, and you're seeing it at varying states of page load which is whatever tags the browser has successfully closed.

Comment: well then it's all about what's not shown; _how_ and _when_ you perform those counts on the iframe content. are you counting comments? are you counting text nodes? namespaces? etc...

Comment: @Radio I have the function that performs the innerHTML grab in a `setTimeout()` at `5000` to wait for the iframes to load. I've varied the time somewhat in other tests but it didn't really make an impact.

Comment: @dandavis There are a few single line HTML comments in each test. I did not include them in my tags count but I can also tell you that every single one of those was picked up. Besides that, I opened up every single tag in my counting (except 4 which got ridiculously large and I gave up).

Comment: a few ideas: there could be content in the `<head>`, whitespace is collapsed (disposes of chars), quirks/invalid content can change counts for sure, tags are rewritten (ex: `<br />` into `<br>`), scripts can be adding or removing content from the body, and external scripts can cloak content "under" them while loading. if the src is local, it would be better to ajax the iframe.src and examine the server response, rather than the parsed iframe body.